# Where do Windows "Product ID" and "Device ID" values come from? Are they useful for Licensing/Identification? How can they be accessed in code?

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: Screenshot of Windows 10 Settings -> System -> About]

As you can see, it has 2 "Hardware-Identity" values that could be very useful in applications like C# for license validating. Is it possible to find these values/compute them manually?

Is it possible it's stored in Registry and is it only for Windows 10?
This is windows Version 1709 Build 16299.15.

Comment: Even better is `Windows.System.Profile.SystemIdentification` which gives you a value that will remain unchanged even if the user reinstalls Windows.

Comment: @RaymondChen Would that be spoofable by easy means?

Comment: Depends on what you consider "easy". The easiest way is probably to just patch your program to detour the call to get the ID.

Comment: The product ID is not a unique number and it can change on Windows 10 with updates to the operating system.

Comment: I would really need to be able to read Device Id from my C# application.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I assume [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180131-00/?p=97945) is yours? Could you explain what is the difference between the "Device ID" described above, and the value returned by `wmic csproduct get uuid`? I expected them to be the same, but they are different (on my system).

Comment: @djvg SystemIdentification is not related to either device id or that wmic thing (neither of which I am familiar with).

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks for the quick response. There seem to be a lot of quasi-unique identifiers in windows. There's also the `MachineGuid`, and probably more that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 15):

1. The Device ID (Advertising ID) is a distinctive number associated with a device. This number is important for technicians and engineers when trying to find solutions to ongoing issues. `And it will change if you reset or install new Windows.`

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient
   ```

   [image: Device ID]
2. The Product ID is the number associated with your particular operating system. `It may change if you install cracked Windows or active Windows with Third-Party activation software.`

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
   ```

   [image: Product ID]

Answer (score 2):

for "Product ID" you can use wmic

cmd com:

```
wmic os get serialnumber
```

C# code:

```
  private string get_com_cmd(string com)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c "+com)
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\"
        };

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Process p = Process.Start(processInfo);
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args_) => sb.AppendLine(args_.Data);
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.WaitForExit();

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

the call:

```
   Console.WriteLine(get_com_cmd("wmic os get serialnumber"));
```

EX cmd output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwrFK.png)

for "Device ID" you can use reg query in cmd or open registry editor by typing the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient your device id in (MachineId) name.

useing cmd by typing

```
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient /v MachineId
```