# How to get Windows 10 Device ID in UWP application?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, deviceid

I am developing a Windows 10 UWP client application which run in company's local network.
The application needs to know Windows 10 Device ID to identify each PC that it's installed on.
You can see value of Windows 10 Device ID in Settings-About page:

[image: Windows 10 Device ID]

I tried to use [`EasClientDeviceInformation.Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.id#Windows_Security_ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning_EasClientDeviceInformation_Id) but its value is different.

How do I do to get Windows 10 Device ID?

Comment: Hey, bro. Did you find the right answer?

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47603786

Answer (score 2):

I think **SystemIdentification** class is what you are looking for. It doesnot provide device id in settings page. But it is used to uniquely identify the device as suggested in Microsoft Docs.

```
var systemId = Windows.System.Profile.SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForPublisher();
```

> Provides information to uniquely identify the system on which the app
>   is running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.systemidentification

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Vignesh. In my case, customer wants to check the device identifier by himself.