# How to get device id from OS?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I want to retrieve the value which is displayed by the (Windows 10) path: Settings -> About ->  Device ID. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-ids) information about this value. But I don't know how to get this using .NET 5. Are there ways to accomplish this without using the UWP?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603786/where-do-windows-product-id-and-device-id-values-come-from-are-they-useful) answer your question? If so, then it's a matter of googling for how to read the registry.

Comment: @NPras yes, it does. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

using Registry you can find DEVICEID, i added the C# code below to get DEVICEID

```
   String PCID = String.Empty;
   RegistryKey localKey;  
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)      
        localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);  
    else 
       localKey =    RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);    
 var RegKEY =    localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient");
 if(RegKEY != null)
 {
   PCID = RegKEY.GetValue("MachineId").ToString().Trim();
  }
```